# Web front-end tools for Grails project

Tags: grails, frontend, gsp

I previously developed only Java SE applications, and now I am trying to do some small project in Grails. My front-end developing skills are really bad. Ok, I got the main ideas behind GSP in Grails, but there are many tools which alow to simplify front-end development, like Twitter Bootstrap.

My question is, what tools for front end are best suited for Grails project and can be naturally combined with GSP?

Another option I am looking into is doing whole front-end on something like Flex, how hard is it to do such thing in Grails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grails is best suited for HTML+CSS+JS front-end. You still can use [Flex](http://grails.org/plugin/flex), [Vaadin](http://grails.org/plugin/vaadin), [GWT](http://grails.org/plugin/gwt), etc., if you prefer. But standard HTML + modern framework is really easier to use.

For standard web app, based on html/css/js, I can recommend [Twitter Bootstrap plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap) (but you aren't limited to it). It's very useful framework, but you should know all basics (html and css)

Comment: Thanks for direct links to Grails plugins. Right now it seems like I'll have to make choice between Twitter Bootstrap and GWT.

Comment: I was using GWT before. Then Vaadin. And now BackboneJS (+Twitter Bootstrap), and think it's better option.

Comment: If you stay with front-end scripting I recommend to get familiar with [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). Here you go with the appropriate [Grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/coffeescript-resources).